# TypeScript empty row in string literal

Tags: typescript, string, string-literals

I want to create a string literal with the optional value numberOfResidents.

```
function mapBuildingToComment(building: Building) {
    return `
    ### Building information ###
    Street: ${building.address.street}
    HouseNumber: ${building.address.houseNumber}
    ${mapNumberOfResidents(building.numberOfResidents)}
    City: ${building.address.city}
    `
}

function mapNumberOfResidents(numberOfResidents?: string) {
    if (!numberOfResidents) return ''

    return `Number of residents: ${numberOfResidents}`
}
```

My problem now is, when numberOfResidents is undefined, there is an empty line in my output.

```
Output:
    ### Building information ###
    Street: Teststreet
    HouseNumber: 1

    City: Test
```

How can I achieve that there is no empty line and City is directly below the house number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the newline and add it only if you need it like

```
function mapBuildingToComment(building: typeof b) {
    return `
    ### Building information ###
    Street: ${building.address.street}
    HouseNumber: ${building.address.houseNumber}\
${building.numberOfResidents ? '\n    ' + mapNumberOfResidents(building.numberOfResidents) : ''}
    City: ${building.address.city}
    `
}

function mapNumberOfResidents(numberOfResidents?: string) {
    if (!numberOfResidents) return ''

    return `Number of residents: ${numberOfResidents}`
}

const b = {address: {street: '123', houseNumber: 245, city: 'asd'}, numberOfResidents: '3'}
console.log(mapBuildingToComment(b))
b.numberOfResidents = ''
console.log(mapBuildingToComment(b))
```

---

another option is to remove empty lines from result with `s.replaceAll(/\n\s+(?=\n)/g, '')`

Comment: Thanks, your Regex helped.